# DB-MYSQL Query help for select where in

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have the create a table called suburb_temperature which basically holds a suburb name, date and temperature as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`suburb_temperature` (
  `idsuburb_temperature` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `suburb_name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `time_value` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `degrees` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idsuburb_temperature`),
  INDEX `suburb_temperature_idx1` (`suburb_name` ASC, `time_value` ASC, `degrees` ASC));
```

I then inserted some data into this table.

```
INSERT INTO `test`.`suburb_temperature` (`suburb_name`, `time_value`, `degrees`) VALUES ('SYDNEY', '2015-06-16', '11.5');
INSERT INTO `test`.`suburb_temperature` (`suburb_name`, `time_value`, `degrees`) VALUES ('SYDNEY', '2015-06-17', '12.5');
INSERT INTO `test`.`suburb_temperature` (`suburb_name`, `time_value`, `degrees`) VALUES ('ULTIMO', '2015-06-16', '11');
INSERT INTO `test`.`suburb_temperature` (`suburb_name`, `time_value`, `degrees`) VALUES ('ULTIMO', '2015-06-17', '11.9');
INSERT INTO `test`.`suburb_temperature` (`suburb_name`, `time_value`, `degrees`) VALUES ('PYRMONT', '2015-06-16', '12.4');
INSERT INTO `test`.`suburb_temperature` (`suburb_name`, `time_value`, `degrees`) VALUES ('PYRMONT', '2015-06-17', '12.8');
INSERT INTO `test`.`suburb_temperature` (`suburb_name`, `time_value`, `degrees`) VALUES ('RIVERWOOD', '2015-06-16', '13.1');
INSERT INTO `test`.`suburb_temperature` (`suburb_name`, `time_value`, `degrees`) VALUES ('RIVERWOOD', '2015-06-17', '12.7');
```

What I'd like to find is the suburb average temperature, minimum temperature and maximum temperature.

I've created the query below which runs, although the **problem** is that no results are returned for suburbs that do not exist in the table. E.G In the query below I entered HAYMARKET as a suburb name which does not exists. No results are returned with a suburb name of HAYMARKET. I need to see HAYMARKET with zero's for the min, max and average in the return results. Does anyone know how this can be achieved efficiently?

```
SELECT suburb_name,
IFNULL(ROUND(avg(suburb_temperature.degrees),2),0) as 'SUBURB_AVG_TEMP_DEGREES_CELCIUS',
IFNULL(ROUND(min(suburb_temperature.degrees),2),0) as 'SUBURB_MIN_TEMP_DEGREES_CELCIUS',
IFNULL(ROUND(max(suburb_temperature.degrees),2),0) as 'SUBURB_MAX_TEMP_DEGREES_CELCIUS'
FROM suburb_temperature
WHERE suburb_name IN('HAYMARET','PYRMONT','RIVERWOOD','SYDNEY','ULTIMO')
GROUP BY suburb_name
ORDER BY suburb_name asc
```

Results for the above query are:
[image: Results]

Comment: I added comment to my answer please follow that steps. Your problem will solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your SQL based on your requirement.

```
 SELECT b.suburb_name,
IFNULL(ROUND(AVG(a.degrees),2),0) AS 'SUBURB_AVG_TEMP_DEGREES_CELCIUS',
IFNULL(ROUND(MIN(a.degrees),2),0) AS 'SUBURB_MIN_TEMP_DEGREES_CELCIUS',
IFNULL(ROUND(MAX(a.degrees),2),0) AS 'SUBURB_MAX_TEMP_DEGREES_CELCIUS'
FROM suburb_temperature AS a RIGHT JOIN  (SELECT 'HAYMARET' AS 'suburb_name' UNION SELECT 'PYRMONT' AS 'suburb_name' UNION SELECT 'RIVERWOOD' AS 'suburb_name' 
UNION SELECT 'SYDNEY' AS 'suburb_name' UNION SELECT 'ULTIMO' AS 'suburb_name') AS b 
ON a.suburb_name = b.suburb_name
GROUP BY suburb_name
ORDER BY suburb_name ASC
```

I think your problem will solved.

Thank you.

Comment: you satisfied my answer can you give a tick mark and up vote please.

Comment: I'm getting Error Code: 1267. Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='

Comment: you can execute these SQL ALTER TABLE test.suburb_temperature CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci; after that upper sql you can execute.

Comment: Hi Venkatesh...Changing the collation in my current environment unfortunately is not an option.

Comment: SELECT 'HAYMARET' AS 'suburb_name' UNION SELECT 'PYRMONT' AS 'suburb_name' UNION SELECT 'RIVERWOOD' AS 'suburb_name' 
UNION SELECT 'SYDNEY' AS 'suburb_name' UNION SELECT 'ULTIMO' AS 'suburb_name' execute sql and see. tell me it gives error or not

Comment: can you come on skype. My skype id is panabakavenkatesh

Comment: SELECT b.suburb_name,
IFNULL(ROUND(AVG(a.degrees),2),0) AS 'SUBURB_AVG_TEMP_DEGREES_CELCIUS',
IFNULL(ROUND(MIN(a.degrees),2),0) AS 'SUBURB_MIN_TEMP_DEGREES_CELCIUS',
IFNULL(ROUND(MAX(a.degrees),2),0) AS 'SUBURB_MAX_TEMP_DEGREES_CELCIUS'
FROM suburb_temperature AS a ==> can you execute these sql and see what happen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80767/discussion-between-peter-h-and-venkatesh-panabaka).